# Macro to copy chart Excel-Word changes chart appearance

Tags: vba, excel

I copy-paste charts from Excel (2010) as images in Word. The copy-paste works but the final chart in Word is different than the original and what I copy-paste manually (Paste special - Picture).

I have tried to change the DataType in the Paste and the Format in the copy but the result is always the same. Any other option?

```
Sub ChartsToWord()

Dim WDApp As Word.Application
Dim WDDoc As Word.Document
Dim iCht As Integer
Dim Msg As String

Set WDApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WDDoc = WDApp.Documents.Add

For iCht = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
   ' copy chart as a picture
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(iCht).Chart.CopyPicture _
    Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap


    WDApp.Selection.Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
    Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False


   WDApp.Selection.MoveEnd wdStory
   WDApp.Selection.Move
Next
WDDoc.SaveAs ("C:\Temp\charts.docx")
WDDoc.Close ' close the document

' Clean up
Set WDDoc = Nothing
Set WDApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try copying the **ChartObject** with the **Copy** Method

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(iCht).Copy
```

And try pasting as a Bitmap or PNG:

```
WDApp.Selection.Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteBitmap, _
Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

WDApp.Selection.range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=14, Placement:=wdInLine, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Comment: It works well but how i could resize it to fit in the page?

Comment: If you need to expand the chart image to fit the Word page, you'll lose clarity as the image is enlarged. But, if you find the width of the Word page, then resize the chartobject accordingly **before** you copy it, then you **should** get the correct sized image in word, with the highest quality.

Comment: It's the other way around, the image is too big in Excel, If I reduce it in Excel it changes it axis which i want to avoid. Resize the image keeping the ratio widht*height is the best option but I can not find how to do it

Comment: Calculate the ratio of the image after it is pasted in, and tore it in a variable. Then adjust the height to a smaller height, and then adjust the width to the new height times the ratio you stored... The new,smaller image will have the same ratio.

Comment: The problem is that I can not select the InlineShape to change any of its dimensions. I am trying   Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Dim pastedImage As InlineShape
    Set pastedImage = doc.InlineShapes(doc.InlineShapes.Count)
    doc.InlineShapes.Item(1).ScaleHeight = 80     or.....
    'pastedImage.LockAspectRatio = True
    'pastedImage.Width = 50     But not modifications in the image

Comment: Try pasting into a bookmark, and then get the shape from the bookmark.